# LuaLaTeX: No error but no output files

Tags: luatex, texniccenter, texworks

I am trying to use LuaLaTeX in TeXnicCenter (or TeXworks as well), due to TeX capacity issues. However, no output files are produced (`.log`, `.pdf`), and I cannot see any error in the build output;

[image: See the image below]

I updated my MiKTeX packages, but nothing changed. I also know there should be no error withing my `*.tex` file, as it was compiled successfully by a friend.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Could you post the complete output if you compile your file using `lualatex POE.tex`.

Comment: @Aditya that was the complete output using LuaLatex->PDF  in TexnicCenter

Comment: Can you post the output when you compile your file from a _command prompt_.

Comment: You have no working format. Go to miktex settings, tab format, select "lualatex" and click on build. If you get an error copy the error message.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is working...I will change the question status to solved...But how can I set a green CORRECT sign right to your comment?

Comment: @user2536125 Fine. And you should learn to really look at the output: You wrote you can't see an error while the second line of screenshots shows the words "fatal" "error" "I' stymied" - and this line has even a gray background.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, by no error, I meant that in the Builder Output, it was stated 'LaTex-Result: 0 Error(s)' ....one last question: How can I point to your comment as being the correct answer?

Comment: @user2536125: I know that you meant this lines. But you should learn to look at the complete output and not only on the summary. The summary doesn't catch everything. And I added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no working format. Go to MiKTeX settings, tab "Format", select "lualatex" and click on build. If you get an error copy the error message.