# LuaLaTeX produces no output

Tags: luatex, miktex, windows

I've decided to switch to LuaLaTeX for superior font support and built-in programming capabilities, but I cannot produce any output. It does not even generate a .log or .aux file. I've come across the thread [LuaLaTeX: No error but no output files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148462/lualatex-no-error-but-no-output-files) and followed the instructions therein, but it did not solve the problem.

Configuration:

- Windows 8.1 64-bit (build 9600)
- MiKTeX 2.9.4503 (64-bit)
- LuaTeX version: beta-0.79.1 (rev 4971)

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This will not compile.
\end{document}
```

Steps taken:

1. Enabled the lualatex and luatex formats in MiKTeX options and built
   all format files.
2. Updated MiKTeX and rebuilt all format files.
3. Tried  invoking lualatex from command line (normally I use TeXnicCenter). The only result I get is the text 'This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 4971)', but no .pdf, .aux or .log files are produced.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the suspected (working) result on Linux, TeXLive 2014

Comment: Sounds as if the format is not correct. How did you rebuild the formats? With miktex settings or with miktex settings (admin)?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Thank you. It must be MiKTeX-specific then.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thank you. I used MiKTeX settings (admin).

Comment: Then try again with the user miktex settings. If you have a user format it takes precedence and the admin tools can't overwrite it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: That did it, thank you very much. Now it works. I'm a newbie and don't know how to mark your comment as an answer, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to recreate the lualatex format.

Try first to do it with miktex-settings (admin). If this doesn't help you probably have a format in your user profile which takes precedence and which the admin tools can't overwrite. In this case you must recreate the format with the user miktex-settings.

Comment: I tried to extend the minimum example a bit with fontspec and immediately I ceased to get any output. Now .log files are generated but .aux files are not. I cannot find any error in the log file. When I run lualatex in the command line, the feedback does end with '*** MultiByteToWideChar() failed for some reason', but this text does not appear in the log. The log stops at the line before that.

Comment: Don't add new questions in a comment. Create a new question and don't forget to *show a complete minimal example*.